# The block number when you await solidity call in javascript

Tags: solidity, javascript

If I await two solidity calls in javascript sequentially:

```
await contract.A().call();
await contract.B().call();
```

does it mean they will guarantee to happen in two different blocks? Thanks.

EDIT: both actions are write actions. I wrote .call() to make the syntax easy here.

Comment: There is no transaction involved when using `.call()` so it won't wait for block between calls. Though it is possible that a block arrives between calls.

Comment: @Ismael Sorry for the confusion I meant for those two methods being transactions. So if they indeed are transactions, then await will guarantee different blocks, is that right?

Comment: Yes and no. With await it should return when the transaction A was mined, so transaction for B will be in a different block. But since Ethereum is a PoW it is possible a chain reorg will put both transaction in the same block. It is very unlikely to happen but the probability is not zero. In any case the transaction's nonce sould determine the transaction ordering, so A will always execute before B. Why do you need the transactions to be in different blocks?